# How to pass `controllers` status to `directive` template function?

Tags: angularjs

Accoding to the current page, i need to change the template. my question is, how to pass the `current` page from `controller` to `directives` template method?

here is my try:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('main', function ($scope) {

    $scope.template = "homePage";

});

var getTemplate = function (page) { //i need $scope.template as params

  if (page == "homePage") {
    return "<button>One Button</button>"
  }

  if (page == "servicePage") {
    return "<button>One Button</button><button>Two Button</button>"
  }

  if (page == "homePage") {
    return "<button>One Button</button><button>Two Button</button><button>Three Button</button>"
  }

}

myApp.directive('galleryMenu', function () {

  return {

    template : getTemplate(template), //$scope.template need to pass

    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

      console.log(scope.template); 

    }

  }

})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RQEyRMeZEGoWVXkE4ovG?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

I am trying like this, but still getting error. what is the correct way to inject the `$route` to `directive`?

```
var galleryMenu = function ($route, $location) {

    return {

        template : function () {

            console.log($route.current.className); //i am not getting!

        },

        link : function () {



        }

    }

}

angular
    .module("tcpApp", ['$route', '$location'])
    .directive('galleryMenu', galleryMenu);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `$routeParams` on your directive declaration, to use it inside the `template` function.

```
myApp.directive('galleryMenu', ['$routeParams', function($routeParams) {
    return {
        template: function () {
            var page = $routeParams.page || 'homePage', // Define a fallback, if $routeParams doesn't have 'page' param
                output;

            switch (page) {
                case "servicePage":
                    output = "<button>One Button</button><button>Two Button</button>";
                    break;

                default:
                case "homePage":
                    output = "<button>One Button</button>";
                    /*
                    NOTE: Or this other, it was confusing to tell which one to use
                    output = "<button>One Button</button><button>Two Button</button><button>Three Button</button>";
                    */
                    break;
            }

            return output;
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}]);
```

## Edit 1:

If you are using `ui-router` switch from `$routeParams` to `$stateParams`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get current url from $state.current and can pass into the directive with the help of templateProvider.

```
myApp.directive('galleryMenu', function () {

  return {

    templateProvider : getTemplate(template), //$scope.template need to pass

    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

      console.log(scope.template); 

    }

  }
```

from getTemplate you can return $state.current. hope so it'll help you.

Comment: Can you please update in demo. i am getting error as `$current` not defined in template method.

Comment: are you using angular-ui router or simple route provider

Comment: simple route provider, but i am using '$route' - on some controller, it woks